# Determine whether the solution of pendulum equation without friction is stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

Let us assume we have the simplest DE of a pendulum, without friction:

$$\frac{d^2\phi}{d t^2}+\omega^2sin(\phi)=0$$

where $\phi$ is the angle of alteration. Boundary and initial conditions: $\phi(t=0)=\phi_0$ and $\frac{d\phi}{d t}=0$. For the sake of simplicity: $\omega=1$. I would like to find a stationary solution, so $$\frac{d}{d t}=0, \frac{d^2\phi}{d t^2}=0$$ Therefore, the next step is to find a solution of the following equation: $$sin(\phi)=0$$ which gives me **two** points: $$\phi=0, \phi=\pi/2$$ Now I want to examine the stability of these points.

If the angle between $\phi$ and the normal is zero, I suppose it is an absolutely stable state *to an external perturbation*, and if $\phi=\pi/2$ the pendulum is placed upside down and this particular state is absolutely unstable *to an external perturbation*.

I tried to find a way to represent this assumption in analytical mathematical form, but I could not get anything. There are many sources to explain what stability is, Lyapunov stability and how to find the stability of the ODE system, but this very example I failed to examine.

Could someone please help me to prove that $\phi=0$ is a stable state and $\phi=\pi/2$ is unstable to external perturbations..
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You know that the energy $E=\frac12\dot ϕ^2+ω^2(1-\cosϕ)$ is a Lyapunov functional at the constant solution $ϕ=0$?

Comment: No, I did not, but my interest is not in energy determination

Comment: @LutzLehmann or maybe I am missing your point? Is  Lyapunov functional somehow connected to the posed question?

Comment: Yes, as soon as you have a first integral you know that solutions follow the level sets. In the case of the Lyapunov function conditions, those level sets around the minimum point are closed and bounded, which here leads to periodic solutions. Thus you get stability, although not asymptotic stability.